# My custom made estimator class is not working with sklearn cross_val_score. TypeError Estimator should have "fit", but it does

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to implement a custom estimator class and use it with sklearn cross_val_score(). I have a "fit", "get_params", and "predict" function, but python is throwing the following error:

TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing "fit" method, "multigaussclassify" was passed.

This is how I am calling my estimator:

```
multigaussclassify = MultiGaussClassify(k_Boston, d_Boston, diag=False)
sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score('multigaussclassify',XBoston50,yBoston50,cv=5,scoring="accuracy")
```

I have been googling solutions for days now, but cannot seem to find anything that is explaining the issue here. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
class MultiGaussClassify:
    
    def __init__(self, k, d, diag):
        
        self.k = k
        self.d = d
        self.diag = diag      
        self.PCi = (1/k) * np.ones((k,1))
        self.Mean = np.zeros((d,k))
        self.Cov = np.dstack([np.identity(d)]*k)
        
    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {"k": self.k, "d": self.d, 'diag': self.diag}
        
    def fit(self, X, y):
        
        # Formatting Data
        d = self.d
        k = self.k
        unique, counts = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
        N = np.sum(counts)
        X = X.reshape((N,d))
        y = y.reshape((N,1))
        
        # Estimating Prior
        self.PCi = counts/N
        self.PCi = self.PCi.reshape((k,1))
        
        # Estimating Mean
        data = np.hstack((X,y))
        for i in range(0,k):
            mtemp = data[np.where(data[:,-1] == i)]
            mtemp = mtemp.sum(axis=0)[:-1]
            mtemp = mtemp/counts[i]
            self.Mean[:,i] = mtemp.T
      
        # Estimating Covariance Matrix
        for i in range(0,k):
            Xtemp = data[np.where(data[:,-1] == i)]
            Xtemp = Xtemp[:,0:d]
            self.Cov[:,:,i] = ((Xtemp-self.Mean[:,i]).T@(Xtemp-self.Mean[:,i]))/counts[i]
        if d > 2:
            self.Cov = self.Cov + np.dstack([0.01*np.identity(d)]*k)
        
        return self
        
    def predict(self, X):
        k = self.k
        d = self.d
        N = np.shape(X)[0]
        X = X.reshape((N,d))
        YPred = np.zeros((N,1))
        for j in range(0,len(X)):
            g = np.zeros((k,1))
            for i in range(0,k):
                if self.diag == False:
                    S_inv = np.linalg.inv(self.Cov[:,:,i])
                    S_det = np.linalg.det(self.Cov[:,:,i])
                    W = -(1/2) * S_inv
                    w = S_inv @ self.Mean[:,i]
                    w0 = -(1/2) * self.Mean[:,i].T @ S_inv @ self.Mean[:,i] - (1/2) * np.log(S_det) + np.log(self.PCi[i])
                    g[i] = np.transpose(X[j,:].reshape(d,1)) @ W @ X[j,:].reshape(d,1) + w.T @ X[j,:].reshape(d,1) + w0
                else:
                    summedTot = 0
                    for l in range(0,d):
                        summed = ((X[j,l] - self.Mean[l,i])/self.Cov[l,l,i])**2
                        summedTot = summedTot+summed
                    g[i] = -(1/2) * summedTot + np.log(self.PCi[i])
            gmax = np.ndarray.max(g)
            for i in range(0,k):
                if g[i] == gmax:
                    YPred[j] = i
            
        return YPred
```

Comment: You passed the string multigaussclassify instead of the multigaussclassify object

Comment: WOW, you have no idea how dumb but relived I feel! Thank you SOOOOO much for finding that for me.

Comment: no problem at all :)